# Go gRPC status.Error() causing invalid memory address when running concurrent requests

Tags: go, grpc

I have a `bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword()` function that if the error is not nil return a status.Error() back to the client.

It works If I don't run concurrent requests.

If I just return the err back to the client instead of `status.Error()` from the bcrypt everything works with concurrent requests. I ran it testing race conditions and nothing came up.

I'm not sure if the issue is with the `"google.golang.org/grpc/status"` library or with `"golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"`. I looked into the status library and there are no reading/writing of maps or anything in my mind that would cause this issue. Any help appreciated.

My code:

```
  package main

import (
    pb "dms-cloud/authentication-microservice/pb"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "golang.org/x/net/context"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
    "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
    "time"
    "encoding/json"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"
)

func (s *server) Authenticate(ctx context.Context, in *pb.AuthenticationRequest) (*pb.Ticket, error) {

    // Verify Password Correct
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(in.EncryptedPassword), []byte(in.Password))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Error(105, "Authentication Failed")
    }

    // Generate Ticket
    tkt := uuid.NewV4()
    exp := time.Now().Unix() + 700

    // Response
    t := pb.Ticket{
        Uuid: tkt.String(),
        TimeExpire: exp,
        AccountId: in.AccountId,
    }

    rTkt, err := json.Marshal(t)

    err = cache.Set(tkt.String(), string(rTkt), time.Minute*60).Err()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, status.Error(500, "Internal Error")
    }

    return &t, nil
}
```

The error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x13d96c5]

goroutine 34 [running]:
main.(*server).Authenticate(0x176f580, 0x1b44000, 0xc420194210, 0xc420192e00, 0x176f580, 0x102906e, 0x0)
        /Users/kenfab/go/src/dms-cloud/authentication-microservice/Authenticate.go:19 +0x105
dms-cloud/authentication-microservice/pb._AuthenticationMicroservice_Authenticate_Handler(0x1453060, 0x176f580, 0x1b44000, 0xc420194210, 0xc420016cd0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/kenfab/go/src/dms-cloud/authentication-microservice/pb/authenticate.pb.go:240 +0x28d
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc4200128c0, 0x1717ec0, 0xc42001b1e0, 0xc42019c000, 0xc420019e60, 0x17464c0, 0xc4201625a0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /Users/kenfab/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:781 +0xc41
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc4200128c0, 0x1717ec0, 0xc42001b1e0, 0xc42019c000, 0xc4201625a0)
        /Users/kenfab/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:981 +0x15a6
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1(0xc420011b50, 0xc4200128c0, 0x1717ec0, 0xc42001b1e0, 0xc42019c000)
        /Users/kenfab/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:551 +0xa9
created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
        /Users/kenfab/go/src/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:552 +0xa1
exit status 2
```

Comment: If the marked line is truly the line where the error is occurring, I'm stumped, because no pointer is dereferenced there.

Comment: Show more of the context in your code. Are you shadowing the `status` package with a `status` variable?

Comment: @JimB I added the whole function

Comment: Per [godoc](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/status#Error), `status.Error` takes code value as type `codes.Code` which is `type Code uint32`. Use the type appropriately. And list of gRPC code per spec is here https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/codes#Code

Comment: @jeevatkm that works but why would it allow other codes that are not 0 - 15 based on [codes](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/codes#Code) and work when there are no concurrent requests.

Comment: Those codes are enum value of [grpc](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/rpc/status#Status) other than that it will fail. Typically you could have got compile error when using incorrect type, not sure why.

Comment: It builds fine without an error. I'm using go version go1.8.1 darwin/amd64

Answer (score 1):

Added a code from [godocs](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/codes#Code) does solve this issue. It only works with 0 - 15. Thank You  @jeevatkm